# Finding a cut maximizing average weight of cut edges

Tags: weighted-graphs, max-cut

Just checking if this version of Max Cut is still NP-hard:

Given a fully connected graph $G(V,E)$, where every vertex is connected to every other vertex, and where every edge has a weight associated with it. Find a cut in $G$ such that the *average* weight of the cut edges is maximal. See the example below, where other cuts may result in more edges cut, but not in a higher average weight.

[image]

Comment: You can find *maximum mean cut* in the literature, but this is a directed problem, whose undirected version seems to correspond to the task of *minimizing* the average cost of a cut edge.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Do you have a reference for the "the task of minimizing the average cost of a cut edge"?
I may be able to transform the problem into a min-cut one, given that the edge weights lie in a certain range.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22maximum+mean+cut%22